# Format title for \chapter*{}

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, chapters, titlesec

I have formatted Chapter titles using the package titlesec, but the formatting is unsuccessful in applying to my chapters with an **asterisk ***, (those chapters which I do not want appearing in my table of contents.)

That is, I would like to center and make `\huge` a title which corresponds to **`\chapter*{Some Title}`**.

For all my other chapters, I have successfully used:

```
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
```

How may I do this for **`\chapter*{}`**, using titlesec or otherwise?

This is under `\documentclass{report}`.

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}

\tableofcontents{}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Unnumbered Title}
\chapter*{Unnumbered Title}
I would like the title above centered

\chapter{Numbered Title}
...centered like this chapter heading above

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Please give us a small, compilable document which reproduces the issue. By default `\titleformat` affects starred as well as unstarred commands. When I try your format command, the title of unstarred chapters i not centred - only the 'Chapter X` bit which is, of course, not relevant for starred chapters.

Comment: @cfr I have reproduced the issue above, thanks for your response!

Answer (score 6):

You can have what you want with the `numberless` key. I'm not sure whether you want unnumbered chapters to be in the table of contents; the below code does  it, but it's easy to undo it if you don't want. Just use:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block] {\normalfont\huge\filcenter\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\huge}[\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\chaptertitle}]
```

Comment: (+1) Just for being able to find it. Why doesn't the documentation mention that there are extensions on page 4 when explaining `\titleformat` as part of the 'Advanced Interface' description. Is that for the 'Very Advanced Interface'? The documentation is... leaves something to be desired.

Comment: It's described in §3.8, *Extended settings*. Perhaps it's because the author, a little further, ‘discourages using starred versions of sectioning commands’ in favour of ‘mark-up oriented commands’ (§ 4.2) with examples.

Comment: Thanks. I found it, actually. But I only found it by searching for the option having seen your solution. I just find the documentation frustrating that different features of the same command are explained in a bunch of different places without even a pointer to those other places.

Comment: @cfr: You're probably right. I guess I don't have this problem only because I've been using the package for more than 15 years. I remember I had difficulties with   `titletoc`.

Comment: It may just be me. Other people seem to get on fine with it ;). I find the documentation looks good... until I actually try to use it. I've got comments in my own code which say things like 'whatever you are thinking of doing with titlesec will be infinitely easier without it' to remind myself of this. But I don't usually find it this difficult to understand package documentation in general. I found `forest` hard but after asking one question and seeing a couple of examples, it started to make sense whereas `titlesec`... I still avoid these packages in my own stuff.

Comment: Making me think of Groucho Marx's sentence: ‘I don’t want to belong to any club that would accept me as one of its members.’